# ImageView increases and decreases dynamically after the size of a textfield

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#272727"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/BtnSlide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/lin" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="100dp"
    android:text="HEADER"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="2.2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

The `ImageView` is placed to the right of the screen. But I'm facing an issue, the `ImageView` increases and decreases in height and width depending on the length of the `TextView`, how can I make this work properly, without the `ImageView` changing size?

Comment: in imagevie remove matchparent and set wrapcontent.try to use relative layout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `ImageView` matches the size of your parent, that is your `LinearLayout` (with id tabBar).

That `LinearLayout` wraps the content on his height, so, it sums all "heights" of his contents. The `LinearLayout` will take the height of `TextView` + the height of the `ImageButton`. Then, the `ImageView` will match that height.

A solution depends on what you are trying to do, but you can try to:

- Set a predefined height in your `ImageView`
- Use a RelativeLayout instead of a `LinearLayout` and align all your views depending on each other

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to set layout_weight to all the components so that their size is fixed regardless of their contents:) See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) for more details